# How to create a private AWS Api Gateway using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create an AWS API Gateway of PRIVATE type,
This requires a resource policy, which I have as I'm able to create the gateway from the AWS Console,
I wanted to know how I could add the resource policy via the CF template -

**Following is the swagger definition of the resource policy -**

```
x-amazon-apigateway-policy:
  Version: "2012-10-17"
  Statement:
  - Effect: "Deny"
    Principal: "*"
    Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
    Resource: "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:awsAccountId:xxxx/*/*/*"
    Condition:
      StringNotEquals:
        aws:sourceVpc: "vpc-xxxxx"
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Principal: "*"
    Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
    Resource: "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:xxxx:xxxx/*/*/*"
```

**How can I configure it in the CF template -**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: G2G Api Template Stack

Resources:
   g2gPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Name: 'private-gw'
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - PRIVATE
```

**Reference -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html

https://medium.com/@cathmgarcia/conditional-resource-policy-on-aws-sam-with-inline-swagger-816ce946dbb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to supply the policy under a key (called `Policy` at the same level as `Name`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-policy

This needs to be supplied in the JSON format.

Something like...

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: G2G Api Template Stack

Resources:
   g2gPrivate:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Name: 'private-gw'
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - PRIVATE
      Policy: !Sub |
        {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Deny",
              "Principal": "*",
              "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:*/*/*/*",
              "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                  "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-xxxxx"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": "*",
              "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:*/*/*/*"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: How can I refer the AWS AccountId and APIGateway within the Policy JSON? Is there a way to use Sub! to fetch the AWSAccountId and how can I refer the same Gateway's Id in the JSON?

Comment: Yeah you can use !Sub. I've updated the example to so it working.

Comment: A small issue here, inside the policy the `Resource` property requires the ApiId the `xxxx` part is the API ID, so in this scenario will I need to create the gateway first and then modify the same resource with the Policy example that you've shared?

Comment: Rather than suppling the ApiID in the Arn, you can use a wildcard '*'

eg `arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:*/*/*/*`

This will be safe as the policy is explicitly associated with this API Gateway.

Comment: No worries. And yeah, I've been doing a lot with CloudFormation and API Gateway for a while now. Its mostly very good but at times, rather frustrating!

Comment: Yea one time pain 

Comment: can you advise on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57815012/aws-cloudformation-unable-to-add-permission-to-lambda-function