# AWS Cloudformation unable to add permission to Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am facing an issue on the Cloudformation template where POST methods are getting created and invoke permissions are being set properly,
But the GET or any non POST methods are getting created but,
 
do not seem to have invocation permission being set properly.

**Following is the working template with the POST method -**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Description: AWS API Gateway with a Lambda Integration

#Creating resusable parameters
Parameters:
  CorsOrigin:
    Type: String
    Default: "'*'"
  CorsHeaders:
    Type: String
    Default: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
  CorsMethods:
    Type: String
    Default: "'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'"

Resources:
  #Creating Lambda to act as a backend, returning Hello world
  BusinessLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          exports.handler = async (event) => {
            let response = {
              'statusCode': 200,
              'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              'body': 'Hello, World!'
            };
            return response;
          };
      Description: AWS Lambda function
      FunctionName: 'BusinessLambda'
      Handler: index.handler
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/ScriptRole'
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Timeout: 15

  #Creating a Lambda function to act as an Authorizer, returns an allow IAM policy
  AuthorizerLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'AuthorizerLambda'
      Handler: handler.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Code:
        S3Bucket: 'some-bucket-name'
        S3Key: 'stage/deployable/authPrivate.zip'
      Description: 'Auth test'
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 15
      Role: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/ScriptRole'

  #Creating an API gateway called => test-api-gw
  RestApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: test-api-gw
      ApiKeySourceType: HEADER
      Description: An API Gateway with a Lambda Integration
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - EDGE

  #Creating a url path called => /test
  RestApiResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt RestApiGateway.RootResourceId
      PathPart: 'test'
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApiGateway

  #Creating an API Gateway Custom Authorizer
  RestApiAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties: 
      AuthorizerUri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${AuthorizerLambda.Arn}/invocations"
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApiGateway
      Type: "REQUEST"
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
      Name: custom_authorizer

  #Providing permission to Lambda to be used as an Authorizer for the API Gateway
  RestApiAuthorizerPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt AuthorizerLambda.Arn
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RestApiGateway}/authorizers/${RestApiAuthorizer}"

  #Creating a POST method with Custom Authorizer
  ApiGatewayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      ApiKeyRequired: false
      AuthorizationType: "CUSTOM"
      AuthorizerId: !Ref RestApiAuthorizer
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        Uri: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${!stageVariables.lambdaAlias}/invocations'
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: $input.json('$')
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: !Ref CorsHeaders
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: !Ref CorsMethods
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: !Ref CorsOrigin
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: $input.json('$')
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
          StatusCode: '200'
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.querystring.name: false
      OperationName: 'lambda'
      ResourceId: !Ref RestApiResource
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApiGateway

  #Enabling CORS by creating an OPTIONS method on /test resource path
  APIGatewayOptionsMethod:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      ResourceId: !Ref RestApiResource
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApiGateway
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      Integration:
        Type: MOCK
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: !Ref CorsHeaders
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: !Ref CorsMethods
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: !Ref CorsOrigin
            ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: ''
            StatusCode: '200'
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: 'Empty'
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: false
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: false
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: false
          StatusCode: '200'

  #Provide permission for API Gateway to Invoke Lambda
  LambdaPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt BusinessLambda.Arn
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RestApiGateway}/*/POST/test"

  #Deploying the API gateway
  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn: ApiGatewayMethod
    Properties:
      Description: Lambda API Deployment
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApiGateway

  #Create a stage on API Gateway called => dev
  ApiGatewayStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiGatewayDeployment
      Description: API GW Stage dev
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApiGateway
      StageName: 'dev'
      Variables: 
        'lambdaAlias' : 'BusinessLambda'
```

**But if I change the method to GET, it doesn't work -**

```
#Creating a GET method with Custom Authorizer
  ApiGatewayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      ApiKeyRequired: false
      AuthorizationType: "CUSTOM"
      AuthorizerId: !Ref RestApiAuthorizer
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "GET"
        Uri: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${!stageVariables.lambdaAlias}/invocations'
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: $input.json('$')
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: !Ref CorsHeaders
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: !Ref CorsMethods
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: !Ref CorsOrigin
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: $input.json('$')
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
          StatusCode: '200'
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.querystring.name: false
      OperationName: 'lambda'
      ResourceId: !Ref RestApiResource
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApiGateway

#Provide permission for API Gateway to Invoke Lambda
  LambdaPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt BusinessLambda.Arn
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RestApiGateway}/*/GET/test"
```

**The code for `AuthorizerLambda` is basically this -**
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/nodejs/index.js

The `/test` API work with `POST HTTP method`,
After changing to `GET HTTP method` I get the following error -

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

I found that in the GET case, the Authorizer is getting called,
But control doesn't get passed to the Business Lambda function.

**To resolve this -**
1. I have to remove the Authorizer from the method
2. Run the add-permission command using CLI
3. Deploy the API
4. Add the Authorizer to the method
5. Deploy again

**Related issue -**
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=240699

[image]

**Do I need to do something like this -**

```
ApiGatewayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      ApiKeyRequired: false
      AuthorizationType: "CUSTOM"
      AuthorizerId: !Ref RestApiAuthorizer
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved by making `IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"`,
So irrespective of the Method's HTTP type,
The IntegrationHttpMethod must always be POST it seems.